# How can I change a blog description to the title of my Instagram post using JavaScript and instafeed.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, instagram, instafeedjs

i am trying to add my latest post of my instagram page in my  portfolio as a blog the image of latest post is added sucessfully but the problem is I want to change blog discription with title of image so i add unique id in image tag which is institle1 but when i try to target it itis showing error of null property please ans....

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    template:'<a href="{{link}}"><img id="institle1" title="{{caption}}" src="{{image}}" /></a>',
target: "post-one",
accessToken: 'accesstoken'
});

let instatitle = document.getElementById("institle1").title;

document.querySelector(".blog .content p").innerHTML = instatitle;
console.log(instatitle);
```

i want to change paragraph content with the image title

Comment: You probably want to utilize the `after` property available that will execute a callback function after the API call (which is asynchronous, and that's why you are not able to find the institle1 in the DOM on the next line). You can move the code that targets the element, grabs the title and updates the paragraph inside that callback. See here for more: https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/wiki/Options-Reference